# Using TokenUtil to Create Credentials in AEM 6.3

Tags: aem, sling, jcr

I'm working on a legacy project that recently upgraded to AEM 6.3. It uses shared cookies to authenticate user across AEM instances. It specifically uses [`TokenUtil`](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/index.html?com/day/crx/security/token/TokenUtil.html) to create the credentials through `createCredentials` method. However, i had this requirement where i should use Service User to login instead the usual `loginAdministrative`.

I've tried to authenticate the repository first before creating the token.

```
    this.repositorySession = this.repository.loginService("myAuthenticatorService", "");
    authInfo = TokenUtil.createCredentials(request, response, this.repository, uid, true);
```

Apparently, the `createCredentials` do calls `loginAdministrative` which is undesirable. So, even though i authenticate the `SlingRepository` against service user it will keep throwing `RepositoryException`.

```
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Compiled Code">
    /* 0: aconst_null
     * 1: astore        5
     * 3: aconst_null
     * 4: astore        6
     * 6: aload_2
     * 7: aconst_null
     * 8: invokeinterface org/apache/sling/jcr/api/SlingRepository.loginAdministrative:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/jcr/Session;
     * 13: astore        5
     * 15: new           org/apache/sling/auth/core/spi/AuthenticationInfo
     * 18: dup
     * 19: ldc           TOKEN
     * 21: aload_3
     * 22: invokespecial org/apache/sling/auth/core/spi/AuthenticationInfo."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
     ....
```

Above is the excerpts from Netbeans inspecting the compiled code.

My question is, are there any alternatives to create a token for given user id properly without relying on `loginAdministrative`? Before i try to implement my own `TokenUtil` by taking a peek on the original implementation..

ps. i could just add my bundle(s) to **Apache Sling Login Admin Whitelist Configuration Fragment** but i don't think this will survive in the long term..

**EDIT**
It seems i cant implement my own TokenUtil as a workaround. Adobe did not expose the `com.day.crx.sling.crx-auth-token` bundle for version 2.5.30. On Maven Repository only [2.4.30](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.day.crx.sling/crx-auth-token/2.4.30) publicly available. i should have contacted Day Care Team for help. The method `TokenAuthenticationHandler.getRepositoryId(bool)` only available for 2.5.30 which used by AEM 6.3.

Comment: I think, you should whitelist it for now, and file a DayCare ticket. Either they fix it - or they can show you an alternative.

Comment: As @AlexanderBerndt said, you should whitelist it. I think (personal opinion) that loginAdministrative has a legit use in this scenario for 6.3/6.4 and unless it's replaced in the core with appropriate workaround, there won't be much more you can do with the given constraints.